# Implemented AbstractUser: adminsite page can not grant permission to user

Tags: django, django-admin

My model (MyUser) implements AbstractUser.
This is my **model.py** file:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
   degree = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'degree',default=1)
   country=models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name=u'country')
   addr=models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name=u'address of user')
```

but, the adminsite page does not give permission to user. What is the issue here?

Find attached figure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxOyN.jpg).